# why does history.replaceState() not work after history.go() method?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser-history

This is an example javascript code

```
function history() {
   window.history.pushState('','','#page1');
   window.history.pushState('','','#page2');
   window.history.pushState('','','#page3');
   window.history.go(-1);
   window.history.replaceState('','','#replaced');
}
// expected result in url is www.somewhere.com/#replaced
// but result is /#page2
```

Actually, I want to navigate first page and replace the history.state

Is there any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the [`history.go()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go) method is asynchronous. The docs on MDN says this:

> This method is asynchronous. Add a listener for the popstate method in order to determine when the navigation has completed.

So `replaceState` is executed **before** `go(-1)` is finished. That's what is causing the behavior.

Use the `popstate` event in combination with the History API to go back and replace the correct state. The `popstate` event is triggered whenever you go back in the states that you have pushed to the history collection. Either using `history.go(-1)`, `history.back()` or pressing the back button in the browser will trigger it.

And if you are saying that you want to go back to the **first** page, then set the `.go()` value to `-2`, for you want to go back two places in the history.

In the event listener check the `location.hash` value of the current location that you are in. This will let you know if you have reached the correct page. Then use `replaceState` to set the state correctly.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  if (window.location.hash === 'page1') {
    window.history.replaceState('','','#replaced');
  }
});

window.history.pushState('','','#page1');
window.history.pushState('','','#page2');
window.history.pushState('','','#page3');
window.history.go(-2);
```